# c++ vector without pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector

I have a `std::vector<Enemy*> enemies` and when i create a new `Enemy` i do `enemies.push_back(this)`. This works for what i'm doing, but i'm wondering if there is a way to have the vector not need pointers to the enemies. I've tried just `std::vector<Enemy>` but it seems to cause a bunch of problems i can't figure out.

ie. - had to change to `enemies.push_back(*this)`, and it caused some linker errors for some reason.

looping through with the following works, but removing the pointers creates issues:

```
void Enemy::updateEnemies(sf::RenderWindow &window) {
    for(std::vector<Enemy*>::iterator it = enemies.begin(); it < enemies.end(); it++) {
        (*it)->update(window);
    }
}
```

Wondering if someone could point me in the direction of using a vector without pointers and loop through it, updating the objects inside it with the same function..

Comment: Why are you doing `push_back(this)` and what led you to believe that the solution was `push_back(*this)`? This is missing from your question... and in C++11 please use smart pointers.

Comment: is that not how you add something to a vector? coming from javascript, `array.push()` is usually the way I did things.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to do push_back(**this**) (emphasis on the `this`).

Comment: for `vector<Enemy>` to work, your class has to be copyable. "a bunch of problems i can't figure out" suggests that your class doesn't behave properly when copied.  It should either behave properly, or have copying disabled. Google for "rule of three" (or "rule of five").

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you have `std::vector<Enemy*>` inside your `Enemy` class.

Comment: It is unusual for an object to add *itself* to a data structure. Where is this `enemies` variable? Is it `static` or `global`? Does the object remove itself in its destructor?

Comment: `enemies` is global right now, i got more errors making it static inside of `Enemy`. And right now the object does remove itself in the destructor. I'm not really familiar with copying, so i'll google that 'rule of three' (or five).

Comment: @Evan Depending on the situation, the rule of three (or five) can become the rule of zero if you use smart pointers.

Comment: @remyabel - I was trying to avoid using pointers if possible, but really just trying to do whatever's best

Comment: @Evan Avoiding pointers is good. What I'm alluding at is since you're clearly making a game, you're going to have to manage resources like textures (which can be expensive to copy). Ergo, pointers are required. But *if* that's the case, use smart pointers.

Comment: If `Enemy` is a base class you'll need to store pointers to avoid slicing and to take advantage of polymorphism.  Smart pointers would be best as mentioned above.

Comment: If you are going to store `Enemy` objects by value (rather than pointer) then adding/removing them in the constructor can become problematic. How do you know which one to remove in the destructor? Also the vector does not contain the same object that the scope creating the object is looking at - a potential source for subtle bugs.

Answer (score 2):

everbody is saying it in comments - but its the answer

use smart pointers

if you dont know how to do that then google

You life is much easier, safer, faster,...

And they are really easy to use - the main trick with using them is to trust them and dont try to get clever or 'help' them

Answer (score 1):

My practice is to make sure the class implements (and makes `public`) all of the following: a default constructor, a copy constructor, an assignment operator, and a destructor.  Then there's no problem with things like `std::vector<Enemy>`. (The default constructor isn't even necessary for vectors, but can be handy for various other things.)

One caveat, though:   when you `push_back()` an `Enemy` into your vector, it's actually a *copy* of the original instance that gets stored. This raises a few gotchas: first, changes to the original (e.g. to the member data of the variable `e` in the `main()` scope of my example below) will not affect the copy stored in the vector. If you're accustomed to working with vectors-of-pointers, this may be surprising.   Second, the implicit construction of copies and the copying of member data will take time, which may or may not have a significant effect on performance. Third, implicit construction and copying may trigger side-effects (you should simply avoid these in your design, wherever possible).

Here's an example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Enemy
{
  public:
    Enemy() : mEvilness( 1 ) {}    // default (i.e. parameterless) constructor
    Enemy( const Enemy& other ) { Copy( other ); } // copy constructor
    Enemy& operator=( const Enemy& other ) { return Copy( other ); } // assignment operator
    ~Enemy() {}  // destructor

    Enemy( int evilness ) : mEvilness( evilness ) {}  // standard constructor

    void Gloat( void ) const
    {
        std::cout << "muahaha";
        for( int i = 0; i < mEvilness; i++ ) std::cout << "ha";
        std::cout << "!\n";
    }

    int mEvilness;

  private:

    // common helper method for copy constructor and assignment operator:
    Enemy& Copy( const Enemy& other )
    {
        mEvilness = other.mEvilness; // make copies of any other member data here
        return *this;
    } 
};


typedef std::vector< Enemy > EnemyHorde;

void AllGloat1( const EnemyHorde& h ) // doesn't matter if you pass by reference...
{
    for( EnemyHorde::const_iterator it = h.begin(); it != h.end(); it++ )
        it->Gloat();
}

void AllGloat2( EnemyHorde h ) // ...or value (but this will take more CPU time)
{
    for( EnemyHorde::const_iterator it = h.begin(); it != h.end(); it++ )
        it->Gloat();
}

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    EnemyHorde h;
    Enemy e( 1 );
    h.push_back( e );
    h.push_back( Enemy( 2 ) ); // even transient Enemy instances get copied and stored
    h.push_back( Enemy( 3 ) );

    AllGloat1( h );
    std::cout << "\n";

    e.mEvilness++;  // this will have no effect on the output because h contains a *copy* of e

    AllGloat2( h );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need a default (parameterless) constructor for `vector<Enemy>` to compile.

Comment: Good to know.  I think I've always made a habit of including one because there are plenty of other situations for which it is helpful (like `Enemy * Sparta = new Enemy[300];`).   In my example above the constructor definitions can of course also be abbreviated by using a default value, and often that makes the most sense: `Enemy( int evilness=1 ) : mEvilness( evilness ) {}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a well-founded answer you have to go one step back - to the design. As far as i see the Enemy objects are registering themselves via constructor in a kind of global list. So far so good.

But how these object are produced ? In this example in Enemy can be construct everywhere

- On the stack as local
- By new (smartpointer)
- As an element in a vector, list, deque ...
- ...

Depending on this, the Enemy-object cant do any reliable statements about its storage. But one thing that all objects share and what is always accessible from inside the object - is the address ('this'). So the solution via pointer is the only solution that is universal for all constructed Enemy-objects. (References are in this context also "a kind of pointer", and other more complicate constructs may also rely on pointers).

A std::vector cant work because you get 2 different objects. To change one of them does not effect the other. That wont work. And it is not possible to switch to smart pointers without changing your design.

There are 2 common solutions:

Managing the listing from 'inside' Enemy in a generally way like in the given example. Expandable with more features like auto delete entries via destructor.....

Managing the listing from 'outside'. Enemy-objects dont register themselves, the generator of the Enemy-objects is responsible for to do it proper (the design pattern 'factory' is a good solution in this case). And you can use smart pointers what is a good idea in most cases.

There are also some more solutions (including some good solutions) unmentioned, they exceed the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need pointers (most of the time) in C++.

A copy will be made when using the `std::vector::push_back()` method.

Example:

```
Enemy evil_wizard;
std::vector<Enemy> enemy_container;
enemy_container.push_back(evil_wizard);
Enemy Evil_knight;
enemy_container.push_back(Evil_knight);
Enemy pink_elephant;
enemy_container.push_back(pink_elephant);
```